# Delphi fall through in case statement

Tags: delphi

In C you can do something like

```c
switch(x) {
  case 'a':
  case 'b': 
    printf("something");
  break;
  case 'c': 
    printf("else");
  break;
}
```

while in Delphi I tried both

```pascal
 case x of
   'a': 
   'b': writeln('something');
   'c': writeln('else');
 end;
```

and

```pascal
 case x of
   ['a','b']: writeln('something');
   'c': writeln('else');
 end;
```

but both of them do not work.

I though of different solutions, e.g. writing a procedure and call it both for 'a' and for 'b', but I was wondering if there was a better solution.
I could also use a goto, like this:

```pascal
 case x of
   'a': goto labelCaseB;
   'b': begin
          labelCaseB:
          writeln('something');
        end;
   'c': writeln('else');
 end;
```

and it works perfectly, but what is the "standard" solution for the fall through in the case statement in Delphi language?

Of course, my actual case is far more complicated: in the example, I would have used an if-else ;)

Comment: I wonder that such question has been upvoted - help contains clear description and examples http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements

Comment: Usually I check the f1/ctrl-f1 help, then Google it, then I come here directly, and if I still cannot find anything, I ask. But I forgot that help is also available for the Pascal language, and not only for VCL-related questions :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphi does not have fall through in case statements. It is one of the major differences between C and Delphi. But in your particular case (sorry about the pun) you can write

```
 case x of
   'a','b': begin
          writeln('something');
        end;
   'c': writeln('else');
 end;
```

Comment: Wow, I am now wondering why I tried ['a','b'] and not 'a','b'... Maybe because I was going crazy with "format". Thank you, I will accept it as soon as I can (still 9 minutes ;)

Comment: @ZioBit The square bracket syntax is valid when testing for sets of chars.  For example:   if x in ['a', 'b'] then ... will work.  You can also use ranges: if x in ['a' .. 'z'] then ... It can be pretty useful and may work better for you that a case statement in some situations.  Regards,

Comment: @MichaelVincent: FYI: You can also use ranges in CASE, ie. _'a','k'..'q','z':_

Comment: Thank you @HeartWare I was aware of ranges in case statements - oddly, I've rarely used them, though.  Regards,